# Spacing: Align vs. Equation

Tags: spacing, equations, align, mdframed

**Can anybody explain where the extra spacing comes from when using an `align` instead of a `equation`?** And does anybody know how to remove it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{myframe}{frametitlebackgroundcolor=green}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mdframed}[style=myframe, frametitle={B}]
    \begin{equation} c^2=a^2+b^2 \end{equation}
  \end{mdframed}
  \begin{mdframed}[style=myframe, frametitle={A}]
    \begin{align} c^2 & =a^2+b^2 \\ & \geq a^2 \end{align}
  \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You get the same behavior if you try a stock `minipage` instead of `mdframed`. The problem is that `align` should never be used at the start of a paragraph; a remedy is to issue `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before `\begin{align}` (but `tcolorbox` is much more powerful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tcolorbox` you can use `ams equation` or `ams algin` special boxes and this gap disappears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{myframe}[1][]{colbacktitle=green,coltitle=black, #1}
\begin{document}
  \begin{myframe}[title=B, ams equation]
    c^2=a^2+b^2 
  \end{myframe}
  \begin{myframe}[title=A, ams align]
    c^2 & =a^2+b^2 \\ & \geq a^2 
  \end{myframe}

  This is a very long long sentence
  \[c^2=a^2+b^2\]

  This is a very long long sentence
    \begin{align} c^2 & =a^2+b^2 \\ & \geq a^2 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am still looking for an explanation of the unexpected behaviour I described however, since I would like to understand the possible limitations of `mdframed` or `align`.