# align vs equation: vertical space before equation

Tags: spacing, equations, align

I want to remove the vertical spacing before `\begin{align*}` so it looks like the vertical spacing before `\begin{equation*}`. To show a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: spacing issue]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

hello. equation:

\begin{equation*}
  a + b = c \\
\end{equation*}

hello. align:

% this \vspace will fix the space issue for a single align environment, but I want a solution
% that addresses the issue for all align environments through the entire document.
%\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{align*}
  a + b = c \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I can see this issue has been posted before here: [Spacing: Align vs. Equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300087/spacing-align-vs-equation)

This I can see the recommendation to use `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` in front of every single align environment. I want a solution that is done once in the header and is applied consistently throughout the entire document.

I also see the accepted answer involves colored boxes with `tcolorbox`: I want something simpler.

Also here:
[align vs equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation)

I see the recommendation to use:

> [fleqn] option and \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

This doesn't work when I try it. Secondly, the `fleqn` option for amsmath is designed to left-align rather than center `align` environments which isn't what I want to do.

I presume this extra spacing is a full paragraph skip? Why does align do that and equation does not? can I remove that with the align environment?

Comment: The difference in spacing is also addressed here: [`align` vs `equation`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try patching `align*`, inserting `\useshortskip` from `nccmath` at the very  beginning, but in my opinion, it is better to use this command manually when necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align*}{\useshortskip}

\begin{document}

hello. equation:
\begin{equation*}
  a + b = c
\end{equation*}

hello. align:
\begin{align*}
  a + b = c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works. Why do you say that it is better to use this command only manually when necessary?

Comment: Because, sometimes, the align environment gets too close from the text above. B. t. w., you already reduce a bit the vertical spacing if you delete the blank line between the text and the environment.