# Space Underneath equation and align

Tags: equations, align, nccmath

`useshortskip` in `nccmath` manually adjusts the space above `align` but doesn't adjust the space below `align`. The following example produces different results in pages 1 and 2.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}

\begin{document}
hello. hello. hello. hello.
\begin{equation}
y=x.
\end{equation}
hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello.\clearpage

hello. hello. hello. hello.\useshortskip
\begin{align}
y=x.
\end{align}
%%%%%%%%%%%HOW CAN I ADJUST THIS SPACE?%%%%%%%%%%%
hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello.

\end{document}
```

How can I control the space following `align`? I tried to apply `align` right after `\end{align}`, but this way leaves a very narrow space different from the space by `\end{equation}`.

P.S. **[amsmath - redefine align to support \abovedisplayshortskip and \belowdisplayshortskip?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385774)** shows some solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd
        {\NCC@ignorepar}
        {\global}
        {\belowdisplayskip\belowdisplayshortskip\global}
        {}
        {}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
hello. hello. hello. hello.
\begin{equation}
y=x.
\end{equation}
hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello.\clearpage

hello. hello. hello. hello.\useshortskip
\begin{align}
y=x.
\end{align}
hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello. hello.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're looking for `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` (and possibly `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip`). No need to `nccmath`.

Comment: [align vs equation: vertical space before equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538435) shows both ```nccmath``` and ```abovedisplayskip``` ways, but I was using ```nccmath```.

Comment: You can add just after \end{align} `\vskip\dimexpr\belowdisplayshortskip-\belowdisplayskip\relax`.

Comment: ```\vskip\dimexpr\belowdisplayshortskip-\belowdisplayskip\relax``` indents the ```hello.``` right after the ```\end{align}```.